# Javascript Class stringify / serialize with array structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, serialization

I was wondering if there is a simple method to serialize the data structure seen below containing a class extension and an array.

Now it seems the array data is lost in the serialize process.

I tried a few different tricks but without result :(

I tried to reconstruct the CheckGreet structure using an Object. I also added a console log inside the check_if_has_greetings function to be sure it is called. Which is the case. So it seems the array structure is not maintained when serializing the data.

Any ideas how to solve this?
And what if the array was holding three.js objects?

```js
class Greet
{
    greet;

    constructor()
    {
        this.greet = [];
    }

    add_greet(new_greet)
    {
        this.greet.push(new_greet);
    }

    get_greet_random()
    {
        if(this.greet.length != 0)
            return this.greet[Math.floor(Math.random(0, this.greet.length))];
        else
            return null;
    }
}

class CheckGreet extends Greet
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        this.has_say_greet = false;
    }

    check_if_has_greetings()
    {
        console.log("in check");
        if(this.get_greet_random() != null)
            this.has_say_greet = true;

        return this.has_say_greet;
    }
}


let checkGreet = new CheckGreet();
checkGreet.add_greet("Hello World");

let serialized_data = JSON.stringify(checkGreet);
let deserialized_data = JSON.parse(serialized_data);

let checkGreet_from_deserialized = Object.assign(new CheckGreet(), deserialized_data);
console.log(checkGreet_from_deserialized.check_if_has_greetings());
```

Comment: Don't use a private property if you want it to be included in `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The output must be "true". After applying your suggestion to remove the private field it seems to work now. I updated the above example.